# rails4, mongoid subtract two Criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have two Document, Picture,   Seen_Picture

simply.

```
Class Picture
    field :likes, type: Integer
    field :is_new, type: Integer
end
```

and

```
Class SeenPicture
    field :picture_id, type: String
    field :is_new, type: Integer
    field :user_id, type: String
end
```

I find Picture's **is_new** field is 1 and not SeenPicture

ex)

```
 Picture(id, likes, is_new) : 
     [
        [BSON::ObjectId('53f7fb5037646412e71b0000'), 2, 1],
        [BSON::ObjectId('53f2aa8b6b6169e2eb010000'), 10, 1]
     ] 


 SeenPicture(id, picture_id, is_new, user_id) : 
    [
         [BSON::ObjectId('53fbe7066b61694eb5000000'), '53f7fb5037646412e71b0000', 1, '53f2aa8b6b6169e2eb010000']
    ]
```

=> nonPicture is **BSON::ObjectId('53f2aa8b6b6169e2eb010000')**  Picture's last document

when I use mysql

```
(Picture.all.pluck(:id)  -  SeenPicture.all.pluck(:id)).sample(1).first
```

In mongodb, how find nonSeen Picture Documents.

Comment: How you wanted your Output!!! how find nonSeen Picture Documents.?? Means what...?

Comment: @RubyOnRails I wanna like array subtract [53f7fb5037646412e71b0000, , ....., 53f7fb5037646412e71b0000] - [53f7fb5037646412e71b0000] => [53f7fb5037646412e71b0000, .....]